# How to compare two JSONArray and find differencer when JSONArrays itself contain JSONObject which in turn contain JSONArray

Tags: comparison, arrays

I am new to this forum.I am trying to compare two directory structure one that is on remote and another one that is on local. 
Currently what I am doing is based on certain things I am making a JSONArray of directury structure from server side(remote) . Same way I am making a JSONArray of directory structure of client side. Now I want to compare those two JSONArray and get the difference between them.

Also I want to maintain the level of directory structure also . Meaning that in the resulting JSONArray the difference should be at proper level which I can may directly with directory.

Please guide me If I make any mistake here as I am new to the forum.

I have tried below code.

```
public static boolean jsonObjsAreEqual (JSONObject js1, JSONObject js2) throws JSONException {
    if (js1 == null || js2 == null) {
        System.out.println(METHOD+"js1 or js2 null");
        return (js1 == js2);
    }
    List<String> l1 =  Arrays.asList(JSONObject.getNames(js1));
    Collections.sort(l1);
    Collections.reverse(l1);
    List<String> l2 =  Arrays.asList(JSONObject.getNames(js2));
    Collections.sort(l2);
    Collections.reverse(l2);
    if (!l1.equals(l2)) {
        return false;
    }
    for (String key : l1) {
        Object val1 = js1.get(key);
        Object val2 = js2.get(key);
        if (val1 instanceof JSONObject) {
            if (!(val2 instanceof JSONObject)) {
                return false;
            }
            if (jsonObjsAreEqual((JSONObject)val1, (JSONObject)val2)) {
                return true;
            }else{
                return false;
            }
        }
        if (val1 instanceof JSONArray) {
            if (!(val2 instanceof JSONArray)) {
                return false;
            }
            JSONArray arr1=JsonSorter.sortJsonByKey((JSONArray) val1, "name");
            JSONArray arr2=JsonSorter.sortJsonByKey((JSONArray) val2, "name");
            int flag=0;
            int count=0;
            int []arr=new int[100];
            for(int k=0;k<arr1.length();k++){
                flag=0;
                for(int l=0;l<arr2.length();l++){
                    boolean returnval=jsonObjsAreEqual((JSONObject)arr1.get(k), (JSONObject)arr2.get(l));
                    if (returnval) {
                        flag=1;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if(flag==0){
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }else{
            if (val1 == null) {
                if (val2 != null) {
                    return false;
                }
            }  else if (!val1.equals(val2)) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

For example I am using below JSONs as arguments;

js1={"JSArray":[{"folder":1,"name":"My Music","innerJSON":[]},{"folder":1,"name":"My Videos","innerJSON":[]},{"folder":1,"name":"RW-By-10-No-New-Folder","innerJSON":[]},{"folder":1,"name":"RW-By-11-plus-New-Folder","innerJSON":[{"folder":1,"name":"ab25249asset.001829.PNG","innerJSON":[]}]},{"folder":1,"name":"My Documents","innerJSON":[]},{"folder":1,"name":"My Tunes","innerJSON":[]},{"folder":1,"name":"Music","innerJSON":[{"folder":1,"name":"ROnly-SubFolder-to-user10","innerJSON":[]}]},{"folder":1,"name":"kamal","innerJSON":[]},{"folder":1,"name":"zxcvb","innerJSON":[]},{"folder":1,"name":"My Pictures","innerJSON":[]},{"folder":1,"name":"abc","innerJSON":[]}]}

js2={"JSArray":[{"folder":1,"name":"Music","innerJSON":[{"folder":0,"name":"Track_12_[1].mp3"},{"folder":1,"name":"ROnly-SubFolder-to-user10","innerJSON":[]},{"folder":0,"name":"08_Track_8.wma"}]},{"folder":1,"name":"My Documents","innerJSON":[{"folder":0,"name":"temp.ico"},{"folder":0,"name":"logo-mdpi.png"}]},{"folder":1,"name":"My Music","innerJSON":[]},{"folder":1,"name":"My Pictures","innerJSON":[{"folder":0,"name":"ab16807asset.JPG"}]},{"folder":1,"name":"My Tunes","innerJSON":[{"folder":0,"name":"dharamshala.jpg"},{"folder":0,"name":"Logo.gif"}]},{"folder":1,"name":"My Videos","innerJSON":[]},{"folder":1,"name":"RW-By-10-No-New-Folder","innerJSON":[]},{"folder":1,"name":"RW-By-11-plus-New-Folder","innerJSON":[{"folder":1,"name":"ab25249asset.001829.PNG","innerJSON":[]}]}]}

Tell me if anything more is needed. I want diff of this type of JSONs. They represent directory structure and file inside them so there can be n level of folder.so need to keep that thing in mind.

In a JSON an "innerJSON" key represents a folder inside a folder upto n level from that folder.

Thanks

Comment: Can you post some code on what you have tried so far, and what errors you get and someone will be able to help.

Comment: Hi ,I posted some code above. I don't get any error but logically I was not able to find the difference between such kind of JSON or you can JSONArray which are there inside that jsons.Its recursive so.

Comment: Mainly I want to compare two directories (one is on client and another on server)